# Meaning of 滅多な事では + Vしない?

Tags: meaning

I found a sentence like this: "滅多な事では物怖じしない".
But the meaning of 滅多(careless) make me don't understand this sentence. Then I searched something similar on the website and I found this: "私は滅多に怒りません" which means "I rarely lose my temper".
So does it mean: " He rarely shows cowardice".
Here the context of the first sentence: "面倒見のいい性格で交友関係が広く, 滅多な事では物怖じしない胆力を持つ".

Answer (score 5):

滅多【めった】 is rarely used outside fixed phrases today, but its original meaning is something like "mindless" or "random", and by extension, "often" or "easy to happen".

- 滅多にVしない: "does not easily V" → "rarely V"
- 滅多なことではVしない "does not V in random occasions" → "(specially) hard to make one V"

Answer (score 1):

滅多 has several meanings.

[image: 滅多の定義]

Based on the context, I think it may be the third definition, in which case the sentence would mean "I have the courage that I would not cower from ordinary events".